# Storing commonly used data in memory

Tags: memory-management, flutter, dart

I am connecting to an api server. After logging in I receive an access and a refresh token. Also user's name, surname, permission list etc. I always use these properties to display / allow something for the user to do. Also with all the requests I should send access token. I am managing logging in process with BLOC pattern but I don't know where to store all my commonly used data. (like this user data) Maybe in a singleton class? So I can get the data from that class before sending a request.

Do you have any recommendation for it? Because I have no idea.

Comment: You have already answered your question. BLoC is one of the common solutions for handling data. Your question might be related to dependency injection. Look at provider or InheritedWidget.

Comment: Look up for `sqflite` or `shared preference`

Comment: @EsenMehmet I thought bloc is just for handling processes like login, register etc. So, is it for holding data as well?

Comment: @AmanKataria I am not looking for external storage

Comment: It's not just for handling the logic, also keeping the data in the memory. Because the BLoC classes will be singleton mostly, so the data you keep there will be the data memory for your applciation.

Comment: @EsenMehmet Ok that's why I was looking for then. However my bloc provider depends on context so I can't use it in non-layout (widget) classes but I need to use it. Like data providers. How to solve this problem?

Comment: If your problem is solved, please accept the right answer and close the issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the some discussion in the comments, I'm adding the answer also.

The BLoC classes not for just handling the logic, also keeping the data for memory.

Inside `StatefulWidget` and `StatelessWidget`, yes you can acces the bloc provider with `context` but for access between bloc, you can simply use `singleton`. So how to create singleton?

There two basic approaches:

```
class Bloc{
....//some logic and variable
}

final bloc = Bloc(); //Singleton object for bloc, it's static because
// it's outside of the Class and it can be directlry accessible for
// any file that imports this file
```

or

```
class Bloc{
....//some logic and variable

Bloc._internal(); // private constructor

static final bloc = Bloc._internal(); // static object which will sent
// through public factory

factory Bloc() => bloc; // when you use this constructor through your
// application, you'll always get same instance

}
```

So, using a bloc inside yet another bloc would be like this:

```
class BlocA{ //this is for second method

final blocB = BlocB();

blocB.method();...

}
```

For the first method up above use the object, that's all.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a singleton class and keep your commonly used data there or create a `Bloc` class and initialize it in the beginning of your app, it will be like a singleton.

If you already using `Bloc`pattern you can do like this:

```
void main() {
  runApp(BlocProvider<UserBloc>(
    builder: (_, bloc) => bloc ?? UserBloc(),
    onDispose: (_, bloc) => bloc.dispose(),
    child: MyApp(),
  ));
}
```

I don't know how your `Bloc` pattern is implemented, but if you doesn't familiar with this `BlocProvider` implementation, I can give you a `BlocProvider` class that I'm using for my apps.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

abstract class BlocBase {
  void dispose();
}

class Provider<B> extends InheritedWidget {
  final B bloc;

  const Provider({
    Key key,
    this.bloc,
    Widget child,
  }): super(key: key, child: child);

  static B of<B>(BuildContext context){
    final type = _typeOf<Provider<B>>();
    Provider<B> provider = context.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(type);
    return provider.bloc;
  }

  static Type _typeOf<B>() => B;

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(Provider<B> oldWidget) => oldWidget.bloc != bloc;
}

class BlocProvider<B> extends StatefulWidget{
  final void Function(BuildContext context, B bloc) onDispose;
  final B Function(BuildContext context, B bloc) builder;
  final Widget child;

  BlocProvider({
    Key key,
    @required this.child,
    @required this.builder,
    @required this.onDispose,
  }) : super(key:key);

  @override
  _BlocProviderState<B> createState() => _BlocProviderState<B>();
}

class _BlocProviderState<B> extends State<BlocProvider<B>>{
  B bloc;

  @override
  void initState(){
    if(widget.builder != null){
      bloc = widget.builder(context, bloc);
    }
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose(){
    if(widget.onDispose != null){
      widget.onDispose(context, bloc);
    }
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Provider(
      bloc: bloc,
      child: widget.child,
    );
  }
}
```

After initialization you will get your main `Bloc` class through injections.
Like this:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final userBloc = Provider.of<UserBloc>(context);
    return MaterialApp(
      home: HomePage(userBloc: userBloc)
  }
}
```

So, `HomePage(userBloc: userBloc)` this is how you will inject your `Bloc` class through your widgets tree.

Another way to keep the data like login information, is to use [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) package. It is a store for simple data, which you can have a quick access. It will save your data in the device.

Hope this will help.

Comment: I use a bloc library. It's flutter_bloc

Comment: Bloc provider needs context to get related bloc but my data access classes are not layout classes. There is no context. How to solve this?

Comment: You can just use your singleton class, and  if you want to save data also in the device, use [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) with your singleton class. You can save your data in the device and also use them in entire app with singleton.